# Microsoft Windows Azure storage: the remote server returned an error 404 not found

Tags: azure, mapreduce, cloud, azure-hdinsight, bigdata

I am constantly getting an error "404 not found".

I have created cluster and storage account and container.

Detailed error that I get is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

This is my code:

```
public static void ConnectToAzureCloudServer()
{
    HadoopJobConfiguration myConfig = new HadoopJobConfiguration();
    myConfig.DeleteOutputFolder = true;
    myConfig.InputPath = "wasb://hdstore12345687@hdstore12345678.blob.core.windows.net/example/data/gutenberg/";
    myConfig.OutputFolder = "wasb://hdstore12345687@hdstore12345678.blob.core.windows.net/out/o";

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HADOOP_HOME", @"C:\apps\dist\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.3.1-25\bin");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", @"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe");

    Uri azureCluster = new Uri("https://HDInsight-My-Demo.azurehdinsight.net");
    string clusterUserName = "hduser";
    string clusterPassword = "Hdinsight@1234";

    // This is the name of the account under which Hadoop will execute jobs.
    // Normally this is just "Hadoop".
    string hadoopUserName = "Hadoop";

    // Azure Storage Information.
    string azureStorageAccount = "hdstore12345678.blob.core.windows.net";
    string azureStorageKey = @"blablabalbNQNUqtSOMEStorGEKeyssbhIvFjfHTg==";
    string azureStorageContainer = "hdstore12345687";

    //string azureStorageContainer = "https://hdstore12345678.blob.core.windows.net/hdstore12345678";

    bool createContinerIfNotExist = true;

    Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.IHadoop myCluster = Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Hadoop.Connect(azureCluster, clusterUserName, hadoopUserName, clusterPassword, azureStorageAccount, azureStorageKey, azureStorageContainer, createContainerIfNotExist);

    //execute mapreduce job
    MapReduceResult jobResult = myCluster.MapReduceJob.Execute<MySimpleMapper, MySimpleReducer>(myConfig);

    int exitCode = jobResult.Info.ExitCode;
    string exitStatus = "Failure";

    if (exitCode == 0) 
        exitStatus = "Success";

    exitStatus = exitCode + " (" + exitStatus + ")";

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Exit Code = " + exitStatus);
    Console.Read();
}
```

I created a output folder in as user/out. I the HadoopJobconfiguration I am setting it to true and it gets deleted!!. so that means it is able to find storage. Then why do I get that error.

[image]

Comment: Can I suggest that you rotate your storage keys if you haven't already...

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by rotate? there are two keys for storage key1 and key2 both are giving same 404 error.

Comment: Independently of your 404 problem, you have posted your storage account key on a public forum... you should probably change it :)