# Azure storage - mapreduce invalid credentials on running C# mapreduce job

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, azure-storage, bigdata

Follow up question on  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419574/microsoft-windows-azure-storage-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-404-not-fou)

I created a container with access type as 'container' and not blob or private still it needs https to get connected!!.

anyway i created cluster multiple times but still I am getting 403: Forbidden or 401 Credentials required. If not connect to company vpn then 404.There should be no SAS issue as I am having access type of container as 'container'

Also I am able to get all container blob list using fiddler rest call: http://nileshhdstore.blob.core.windows.net/nileshhdstore?restype=container&comp=list

When I run my dot net code (Please see my .net C# code at the top) i get the 401 or 403 error. When i check my blob i see that reducer and mapper exe are uploaded in the blob.

[image]

I went through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx.

I have no clue how to add header in the above mapreduce code. I know I have added azure storage key but its not helping out. its been more than a week and I am already late on the proof of concept.

Comment: As I know, if your request is older than 15 minutes, you will get 403 error. Please check your request x-ms-date header to see whether this caused your issue.

Comment: Even I thought about it. and tried to sync my laptop timezone with sametime zone of headnode (which was in EAST US). (both UTC timezone) It didnt help. same error.